# How get the list of all data from firebase query when passing query in Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a firebase query. I have added "addValueEventListener" to it. "onDataChange" in "dataSnapshot", I see all 3 the child data which should be fetch by the query.

Now, I am passing this query reference in Firebase Recycler Adapter to create recycler view but I see only one data on the view not all 3childs data.

// This is how I am creating the query reference.

```
currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ordersRef = mDatabase.child("orders");
ordersQuery = ordersRef.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(currentUser.getUid().toString());

ordersQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            isOrdersEmpty = ! dataSnapshot.hasChildren();
            Log.i("ORDERS: ", "You have orders: " + isOrdersEmpty + dataSnapshot);

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("ORDER: ", "Your ORDER : " + snapshot);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
});
```

After this, I pass this query reference in Firebase Recycler Adapter

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Orders, OrdersActivity.OrdersViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Orders, OrdersViewHolder>(
        Orders.class,
        R.layout.orders_list,
        OrdersActivity.OrdersViewHolder.class,
        ordersQuery
) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(OrdersViewHolder viewHolder, Orders model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setOrderId(model.getOrderId());
        viewHolder.setTxnAmount(model.getTxnAmount());
        viewHolder.setTxnId(model.getTxnId());

        final String orderId = getRef(position).getKey().toString();

        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent orderDetailActivity = new Intent(OrdersActivity.this, OrderDetailActivity.class);
                orderDetailActivity.putExtra("orderId", orderId);
                startActivity(orderDetailActivity);
            }
        });
    }
};

mOrdersRecyclerView.setAdapter(FBRA);
```

When I see the view in the app, It only shows one data while it should show 3 data.

Comment: Please add your database structure to see those 3 childs clearly.